# Getting a glitch when using scrollTop (page goes to 0 position and then does required animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop, animated

My auto scroll is working properly if scroller position = 0;

But if I manually scroll down a little-bit and scroller position changes from 0 to something let's say 120.

After clicking on a link it takes me back to 0 at first (very fast 0.1sec) an then back to 120 and starts animation and goes to specific element. But this looks like bug which I want to avoid.

I was looking around trying to find a solution in other similar posts. nothing particular unfortunately!

Here is my code:

```
Function Scroll_C(name,time) {  
    $("body,html").animate({ scrollTop: $(name).offset().top }, time);
};
```

Comment: How are you calling Scroll_C? What's the link's href?

Comment: I'm calling it from <map> tag using onClik:

<area shape="circle" coords="64,108,32" onClick="Scroll_C('#about',800);"  href="#"/>

Comment: Try adding `return false;` inside `onClick="` before the Scroll_C call.